# How to configure Apache Camel's serviceCall to look for services in Eureka service discovery?

Tags: apache-camel, microservices, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I am working on a project and I am forced to not using Spring Boot. I have a Eureka server running on localhost:8090 and some services already registered on it.
How can I force Apache Camel's serviceCall to look for services on the Eureka server?
I know that to make it work for Consul as the service discovery you should do something like following:

```
ConsulConfiguration config = new ConsulConfiguration();
config.setUrl("http://ip:port");
ConsulServiceDiscovery discovery = new ConsulServiceDiscovery(config);
// configure camel service call
ServiceCallConfigurationDefinition config = new ServiceCallConfigurationDefinition();
//config.setServiceDiscovery(servers);
// register configuration
camelContext.setServiceCallConfiguration(config);
```

How to make it work for Eureka server on localhost:8090??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Luca suggested and after some research I came to this conclusion that you should implement a custom service discovery to read from Eureka. In order to do that I did the following:

1. Extending my *EurekaServiceDiscovery* class from [*DefaultServiceDiscovery*](https://github.com/Talend/apache-camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/cloud/DefaultServiceDiscovery.java) class of *camel-core* module
2. Overriding the method *public List getServices(String name)* of 
   *DefaultServiceDiscovery* class which is responsible to retrieve services from Eureka
3. Using [Eureka REST API](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations) to get all the services in the overrided method. In order to do this you should convert the recieved JSON data from Eureka REST API to appropriate java classes. You need to define *Application* and *InstanceInfo* classes based on those JSON data.

For example after running Eureka on *localhost:8090* and after registering a service named account-service on it, you can git information of account-service by sending a *Http.GET* request to *localhost:8090/eureka/apps/account-service*

For more info look at this Github repo: https://github.com/hamedmirzaei/service-gateway-bootless

Answer (score 2):

there’s no direct support for eureka in camel so if you can’t use spring-boot, you need to build your own ServiceDiscovery implementation

Comment: If this is the case, how camel finds out about eureka in spring-boot?! I mean there should be some configuration

Comment: it does leverage spring cloud service discovery API so the actual implementation is hidden for camel point of view